# http server on top of net server

Tags: node.js, express, tcp, server

I implemented 2 webservers with express. One is the main, one is a microservice.

They are communicating through a HTTP REST API, and we had historically a socket.io server started on the microservice to watch the up/down status from the main server.

```
              ----HTTP-----
[main server]               [microservice]
              --socket.io--
```

I then realized that socket.io is not the right tool for that. So I decided to trade socket.io for a raw TCP socket.

So the question is : **Is that possible to start the http server "ON TOP" of a raw TCP server (on the same port) ?** (allowing to connect via TCP client AND to send HTTP requests ?)

I have this so far :

```
  const app = express();
  const server = http.createServer(app);
  // const io = sio(server);
  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, callback);
```

and I'm trying to integrate with [this](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757#file-nodejs-tcp-example-js-L9-L16)

What I'm trying to achieve, and achieved successuly with socket.io, is starting a socket server on the microservice, connect to it on the main server, keep it alive, and watch for events to keep a global variable boolean "connected" in sync with it. I'm using this variable to aknowledge the my frontend of microservice state, also to pre-check if I should try to request the microservice when requested, and also for loggin purposes. I'd like to avoid manual polling, firstly for maintenability, and also for realtime purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible to start the http server "ON TOP" of a raw TCP server (on the same port) ?

Sort of, not really.  HTTP runs on top of TCP.  So, you could technically open a raw TCP server and then write your own code to parse incoming HTTP requests and send out legal HTTP responses.  But, now you've just written your own HTTP server so it's no longer raw TCP.

The challenge with trying to have a single server that accepts both HTTP and some other protocol is that your server has to be able to figure out for any given incoming packets, what it is supposed to do with it.  Is it an HTTP request?  Or is it your other type of custom request.  It would be technically feasible to write such a thing.

Or, you could use the webSocket technique that starts out as an HTTP request, but requests an upgrade to some other protocol using the `upgrade` header.  It is fully defined in the http spec how to do this.

But, unless you have some network restriction that you can only have one server or one open port, I'd ask why?  It's a complicated way to do things.  It doesn't really cost anything to just use a different port and a different listening server for the different type of communication.  And, when each server is listening only for one type of traffic, things are a heck of a lot simpler.  You can use a standard HTTP server for your HTTP requests and you can use your own custom TCP server for your custom TCP requests.

---

I can't really tell from your question what the real problem is here that you're trying to solve.  If you just want to test if your HTTP server is up/down, then use some external process that just queries one of your HTTP REST API calls every once in a while and then discerns whether the server is responding as expected.  There are many existing bodies of code that can be configured to do this too (it's a common task to check on the well being of a web server).

The code you link to shows a sample server that just sends back any message that it receives (called an echo server).  This is just a classic test server for a client to connect to as a test.  The second code block is a sample piece of client code to connect to a server, send a short message and then disconnect.

---

From your comments:

> The underlying TCP server wouldn't even be used for messaging, it just would be used to watch connect/disconnect events

The http server already inherits from a TCP server so it has all the same events for the server itself.  You can see all those events in the [http server doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server).  I don't know exactly what you want, but there are server lifetime events such as:

```
listening   (server now listening)
close       (server now closed)
```

And, there are server activity events such as:

```
connect     (new client connected)
request     (new client issues a request)
```

And, from the request event, you can get both the `httpClientRequest` and `httpServerResponse` objects which allow you to monitor the lifetime of an individual connection, including event get the actual socket object of an incoming connection.

Here's a [code example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect) for the `connect` event right in the http server doc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand. I was wondering if there is something like this embedded in node.js, something like `http.createServer(net.createServer(port))`..
*It doesn't really cost anything to just use a different port*. Well, in a complex architecture, with say 5 microservices, replicated, this may lead to a lot of configuration.

Comment: *just queries one of your HTTP REST API calls every once in a while* realtime is a requirement, and polling is not a solution for us (performance mainly)

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON - Well, the only way you can see if a web server is active and responding is to poll it once in a while. I guess I really have no idea what your requirement is then if that is somehow forbidden.  I've told you what I can tell you given what you've put in your question.  If you want to add more relevant information about your actual requirements, then I can take a look again in the morning. And, what exactly would you be expecting `http.createServer(net.createServer(port))` to do?  Seriously tell us what your real requirement is and then, and only then, can we offer you solutions.

Comment: *Well, the only way you can see if a web server is active and responding is to poll it once in a while.*.
Well, basicaly no ? You can watch the connect/disconnect event on a socket left open. (even if it implies underlying polling/heartbeat/keepalive in the module)

Comment: *what exactly would you be expecting http.createServer(net.createServer(port)) to do* precisely to open a TCP server, and open an HTTP parser on top of it, which would "grab" HTTP-formatted messages. The underlying TCP server wouldn't even be used for messaging, it just would be used to watch connect/disconnect events

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON - See what I added to the end of my message.  I didn't realize you were trying to monitor the server from within the process.  From within the process, there are tons of events you can monitor that will tell you about the server lifetime and about each individual client connection that comes and goes.  You can have access to all that.  I've given you some examples at the end of my answer, but all of that is in the http module documentation.  In addition to that doc, an http server is also an instance of net.server so all of its events.

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON - And, in the server's `request` event, you can the `httpClientRequest` object which also contains the actual net.socket object that represents the connection so you can use all the net.Socket events too to track an individual client connection.

Comment: Thanks. "an http server is also an instance of net.server so all of its events" just lead me to, simply, listening to events on a `new net.Socket()` bound to the same url:port that my REST service :). I just have to deal with timeouts (probably inherited from http server config)

Comment: (but I'm not trying to monitor within the process)